# Adding new elements won't make the modal body bigger in Twitter-Bootstraps

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">My title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="problem_desc">

                </div>
                <div id="problem_sol">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div id="modalbutton">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I use some ajax to fill the divs, something like this:

```
$('#problem_desc').html('<div class="form-group error">'+data.problem.problem_description+'</div>');
```

...

```
$('#problem_sol').html(<div class="form-group error"> <label for="probselect" 

class="col-sm-3 control-label">Something</label><div class="col-sm-9"> 

<select class="form-control" id="probselect"></select></div>);
```

I use these functions 2 or 3 times to make a form in the modal

There are several cases of what I want to include in the modal depending on the AJAX response, so I can't just put the form in the modal and fill it with AJAX. I need to create the form dynamically.

I expect the modal's body to expand or contract depending on the amount of divs and columns that I add. This works when I don't add them dynamically.

The problem is that, when added with jQuery, it won't expand or contract and the form will end up in the overlapping the footer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Bootstrap tells the modal how wide it should be at various viewport sizes, i.e. `@media (min-width: 768px) { .modal-dialog { width: 600px; margin: 30px auto; } }`. You will need to override such rules to allow it to expand as content is added. Bootstrap does include `modal-lg` and `modal-sm` but it's unlikely that those modifier classes will give you the results that you're looking for.

Comment: @hungerstar modal-lg only makes it wider. But thanks.

Comment: Like I said, _"Bootstrap does include `.modal-lg` and `.modal-sm` **but it's unlikely that those modifier classes will give you the results that you're looking for**."_ Perhaps you could provide a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overrode .modal-body with this:

```
.modal-body {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Works like a charm.